# onCreateViewHolder is being called only half of the times the actual count returned by getItemCount - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am currently working with an Android App using [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and [CardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) .I am showing lists of UserPosts(Contains text and Image both) inside RecyclerView . The UserPost item has been created using CardView .

**Edit**

The problem I am facing here is **onCreateViewHolder** method is being called only half of the times the actual count returned by **getItemCount** method even I scrolls till end of the list .E.g I have a list of 10 posts then **onCreateViewHolder** calls for 5 times only . It should call 10 times (when I scroll till end of the list) first and then created views will be recycled . But it is not happening actually . I have visited many Stackoverflow posts but no luck .

Here is code **UserPostAdapter.java** :

```
    package com.adapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.model.UserPostsListItem;
import com.musomeet.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.List;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

/**
 * Created by SI_Android on 10/21/2015 .
 *
 */

public class UserPostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserPostAdapter.UserPostViewHolder> {

    private List<UserPostsListItem> userPostList;
    Context conetxt ;
    LayoutInflater inflater ;
    public UserPostAdapter(){

    }
    public UserPostAdapter(Context conetxt, List<UserPostsListItem> postlist) {
        this.userPostList = postlist;
        this.conetxt = conetxt ;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.conetxt);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //int size = 0 ;
        //if( userPostList != null )
            //size = userPostList.size();
        return userPostList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserPostViewHolder videoViewHolder, int position) {

        UserPostsListItem item = userPostList.get(position);
        videoViewHolder.userName.setText(item.getName());
        videoViewHolder.userLocation.setText(item.getCity()+", "+item.getCountry());
        videoViewHolder.timeAgo.setText(item.getAgo());
        videoViewHolder.likes.setText(item.getNo_of_likes());
        videoViewHolder.comments.setText(item.getNo_of_comments());
        videoViewHolder.userMessage.setText(item.getContent());

      if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getPhoto())) {
            Picasso.with(conetxt).load(item.getPhoto()).into(videoViewHolder.circleImageView);
        }
        String url = item.getAttachment_url() ;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
            if ((url.endsWith(".png") || url.endsWith(".jpg"))) {
                //videoViewHolder.attachment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(conetxt).load(url).into(videoViewHolder.attachment);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public UserPostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userposts_listitem_textmessage, viewGroup, false);
        return new UserPostViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    public static class UserPostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView userName, userLocation, timeAgo, likes, comments, userMessage;
        ImageView attachment;
        CircleImageView circleImageView;
        public UserPostViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            attachment = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.attachment);
            circleImageView = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.circleView);
            userMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.massage);
            userName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            userLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.location);
            timeAgo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
            likes = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.likespoints);
            comments = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.commentspoints);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **userposts_listitem_textmessage.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/userpopstcardview"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    cardView:cardElevation="5dp"
    cardView:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    cardView:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/contact"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/circleView"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Jasmine"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#929292"
        android:text="Los Angles, California"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#929292"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#929292"
                android:text="2 hours ago"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/userListContentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/massage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/recet_text"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/attachment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:tint="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/contact"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/likespoints"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#929292"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Likes"
                android:textColor="#929292"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/commentspoints"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="#929292"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Comments"
                android:textColor="#929292"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#eeeeee"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/like"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Like"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#929292"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_effect"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="1dp">
                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#eeeeee"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/comment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Comment"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#929292"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_effect"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="1dp">
                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#eeeeee"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/share"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Share"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#929292"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_effect"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the views don't get created even when the user scrolls?

Comment: Thanks Shubham , You are right ,I am facing the same problem as you are getting .

Comment: I am not facing this problem. You should add this statement to your question as @Kazuki's answer mentioned an important concept but wasn't relevant to your question as you didn't mentioned when the items aren't being created.

Comment: "It should call 10 times first and then created views will be recycled." - This is not correct.

Comment: Do you mean you're only seeing half of your list items the RecyclerView?

Comment: @Mike M No . I am seeing all 10 items , but here 5 views are being recycled for 10 items , according to my knowledge it should not .There should be a unique view for each position of RecyclerView a single view should not reuse on more than one position .

Comment: You assumption is incorrect. That's the whole point of recycling Views; so you can give it a list of thousands of items, but it doesn't need to keep thousands of Views in memory.

Comment: @MikeM. then what it should be .

Comment: Kazuki's answer is the correct explanation.

Comment: [This diagram](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/9ec060191347dd366729c095b529ed21e763a075/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f535a38694b75752e6a7067) might help you to better understand. It's actually describing a ListView, but the same basic mechanism applies to RecyclerView. You can see that when the first item goes off-screen on top, its View is recycled, becomes the eighth item, and scrolls on-screen from the bottom.

Comment: @Mike M. Thanks ,Your comments are really helpfull to me .But if it is expected behaviour of RecyclerView then why I am getting a single image on more than one userposts .

Comment: I am asking about the ImageView which has @+id/attachment" in above userposts_listitem_textmessage.xml file .

Comment: Uncertain. Check to make sure that your execution is entering the `if ((url.endsWith(".png") || url.endsWith(".jpg")))` block. If that condition isn't `true`, then the ImageView's image won't get changed, and it will be the same image that was last set on it, before its View was recycled.

Comment: @Mike M. Yes execution is entering to if() section only once ,since I have only one image . But I am seeing this image on more than one userposts .

Comment: Right, because the View is being recycled. You have to set the image every time `onBindViewHolder()` is called, or it's going to be the same image from the last time it got set. When a View is recycled, it doesn't get "reset" to its original state.

Comment: @Mike M. Can you please put above comment as an answer with the code snippet of onBindViewHolder() in UserPostAdapter.java .

Comment: I have tried but I am still facing the issue .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95784/discussion-between-mike-m-and-android-dev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a View is recycled, it doesn't get "reset" to its original state, so it and its child Views still have the attributes that were set on them the last time the ViewHolder was passed into `onBindViewHolder()`. Since you are currently only setting the image when your `if` conditions are `true`, the ImageView is not updated if either of those conditions is `false`, and it will still have the image set on it previously. You simply need to set the ImageView's Bitmap to null when those conditions are not `true`. Also, your two `if` statements can be combined:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserPostViewHolder videoViewHolder, int position) {

    UserPostsListItem item = userPostList.get(position);
    ...

    String url = item.getAttachment_url() ;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url) && (url.endsWith(".png") || url.endsWith(".jpg"))) {
        Picasso.with(conetxt).load(url).into(videoViewHolder.attachment);
    }
    else {
        videoViewHolder.attachment.setImageBitmap(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have upvoated Kazuki answer also .

Answer (score 3):

What you see is an expected behaviour. RecylerView won't create as many view as adapter's getItemCount() returns. It create view as many as it's necessary for rendering a view.

For instance, if your adapter contains 100 elements, but only 5 are displayed at at time, system will create 5 views (it may create 1 or 2 more view as "buffer") and reuse these views when user scrolls.

Comment: Thanks Kazuki , I know that RecyclerView creates view as many as it's necessary for rendering a view , but in my case RecyclerView is creating 5 views only for all 10 items ,even I scrolls till end of the list .

Comment: Yes, **that** is called "view recycling". Well okay that is not entirely true, that is view caching. It reuses the views so that it doesn't have to inflate them again and again.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce The case of resuse comes when a view is created for a particular position of RecyclerView . When RecyclerView creates 5 views then they should recycle for 5 position of RecyclerView only  ,they should not recycling for all remaining positions (6-10) ,in my case it is happenning ,5 views are recycling for remaining positions (6-10) .